# How to monitor each instance through azure application insight

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have deployed an web-service with 2 instances in azure and i want to monitor request on each instance separately through application insight. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Are the instances scaled, or are they deployed separately?

Comment: what exactly would you like to monitor?

Comment: I want to monitor request failure on each instance separately.

Comment: The instances are scaled

Answer (score 0):

You can create an automated flow to query your requests data and send you an email whenever the query result passes some threshold.
The Application Insights Connector which works both for Flow and Microsoft Logic Apps was created just for that, and can be defined on any query result from any document type (event, metric or even traces).
Step-by-step documentation on how to create your own flow are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-automate-with-flow).

For your needs, a simple query looking at the request failure should look like:

```
let window = 10m;
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(window)
| summarize failures = countif(success == false), total = count() by cloud_RoleInstance
| project cloud_RoleInstance, failureRate = todouble(failures) / total
```